# Монетезация страницы на GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages, рся-яндекс

возможно ли такое, что имея страницу на GitHub Pages (с доменом github.io), публиковать там рекламу (RTB блоки различных ресурсов). Теоретически РСЯ (Рекламная Сеть Яндекса) может одобрить заявку на такой сайт? Или же можно сменить домен страницы на свой бесплатно или максимально бюджетно? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, если сайт стоящий, то РСЯ одобрит заявку. На гитхаб пейджес можно заменить бесплатный домен на тот, которым ты владеешь. [image]

Заходишь в настройки репозитория, как на картинке, и меняешь.
Теперь Гитхаб знает о нашем домене, однако, этого недостаточно — нужно изменить информацию о DNS-записях самого домена, для этого нам необходимо перейти на сайт доменного регистратора, где домен был куплен.
Нужно настроить A-запись домена, для этого перейдём в панель управления DNS-записями, найдём (или добавим) A-запись и укажем «192.30.252.153» в качестве её значения.
[image]

как-то так. Частично украдено от [сюда](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/boost/tools/github-as-hosting)